# doing deep copy vector of pointers in copy constructor got both vector member changed?

Tags: c++, vector, copy, copy-constructor, deep-copy

i need deep copy in my project and for now i `memcpy` the `srcObj` into `destObj` then
if `destObj` owns pointer members, i just create all the obj and do this method recursively

here's the pseudo:

```
class B
{
public:
    B(int id_) : id(id_) {};
    int id = 0;
};

class A
{
public:
    vector<B*> vecInt;
    B objB = 111;
    A()
    {
        vecInt.push_back(new B(1));
        vecInt.push_back(new B(2));
        vecInt.push_back(new B(3));
    }
    A(const A& rhs)
    {
        memcpy(this, &rhs, sizeof(A));
        for (auto i = 0; i < rhs.vecInt.size(); i++)
        {
            auto ptrTmp = new B(rhs.vecInt[i]->id);
            cout << "00000000000 " << rhs.vecInt[i] << endl;;
            this->vecInt[i] = ptrTmp;
            cout << "11111111111 " << ptrTmp << endl;;
            cout << "22222222222 " << rhs.vecInt[i] << endl;;
        }
    }
};
```

here's the issue, every time i assign `this->vecInt[i]` within the loop, the `rhs.vecInt[i]` changes too and they both indicate to one address, i have no idea why this happened.

appreciate any help.

Comment: The `memcpy` causes undefined behaviour. There are few situations where `memcpy` is valid in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memcpy()` is absolutely wrong and needs to be removed. It is corrupting your `A` object’s data members. It *may* work for the `objB` member, but definitely not the `vecInt` member.

But, even with thae `memcpy()` removed, you would still have *undefined behavior* as you are trying to assign to `vector` elements that don’t exist yet. To deep-copy a vector of pointers, you have no choice but to clone each dynamic `B` object one at a time and add it to the new `vector`.

The *correct* way to implement your copy constructor should look more like this instead:

```
    A(const A& rhs) : objB(rhs.objB)
    {
        vecInt.reserve(rhs.vecInt.size());
        for (auto *elem : rhs.vecInt)
        {
            vecInt.push_back(new B(*elem));
        }
    }
```

You also need to add a destructor, move constructor, copy assignment operator, and move assignment operator, per the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three):

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    vector<B*> vecInt;
    B objB = 111;

    A()
    {
        vecInt.push_back(new B(1));
        vecInt.push_back(new B(2));
        vecInt.push_back(new B(3));
    }

    A(const A& rhs) : objB(rhs.objB)
    {
        vecInt.reserve(rhs.vecInt.size());
        for (auto *elem : rhs.vecInt)
        {
            vecInt.push_back(new B(*elem));
        }
    }

    A(A&& rhs) : vecInt(move(rhs.vecInt)), objB(move(rhs.objB)) {}

    ~A()
    {
        for(auto *elem : vecInt)
            delete elem;
    }

    A& operator=(A rhs)
    {
        vecInt.swap(rhs.vecInt);
        objB.id = rhs.objB.id;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

That being said, consider using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<B>>` instead of `std::vector<B*>`. That will eliminate the need for an explicit destructor. Don’t use `new`/`delete` in modern C++ if you can avoid it.

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    vector<unique_ptr<B>> vecInt;
    B objB = 111;

    A()
    {
        vecInt.push_back(make_unique<B>(1));
        vecInt.push_back(make_unique<B>(2));
        vecInt.push_back(make_unique<B>(3));
    }

    A(const A& rhs) : objB(rhs.objB)
    {
        vecInt.reserve(rhs.vecInt.size());
        for (auto &elem : rhs.vecInt)
        {
            vecInt.push_back(make_unique<B>(*elem));
        }
    }

    A(A&& rhs) : vecInt(move(rhs.vecInt)), objB(move(rhs.objB)) {}

    ~A() = default;

    A& operator=(A rhs)
    {
        vecInt.swap(rhs.vecInt);
        objB.id = rhs.objB.id;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Even better, just use `std::vector<B>` instead, and let the compiler handle everything else for you:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    vector<B> vecInt;
    B objB = 111;

    A()
    {
        vecInt.emplace_back(1);
        vecInt.emplace_back(2);
        vecInt.emplace_back(3);
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for your kindly help, i haven noticed the `memcpy` is so vicious and it works now, nevertheless since there are so many pointers i need to use for some objects, i guess i just cannot achieve the last one. but since now the `memcpy` cannot be used, is that supposed i should just assign all of the data members one by one, i just feel like that's really hard to maintain, or is there other methods to handle the situation when there are so many data members?